# Setting width of Audio Player to screen width

Tags: css, html, html5-audio

I'm trying out HTML5 with the audio tag. And I'm trying to get the player to be the full width of the page. I set the padding and margin for body and also the entire document to 0px, and while I can eliminate the margin from the top of the page, the player still doesn't stretch to the full width of the page. I'm wondering if there's some sort of max width for the player, because I've applied no margin and padding to the entire document, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks! Code is below:

PS: I'm ignoring Firefox for now, and using Chrome

Edit: I tested the stretch of the body element by changing the color, and it filled the entire page, so I feel like there has to be some sort of width limit, any workarounds?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Zhaden's OST Playlist</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <audio id="audioBar" autoplay controls>
            <source src="C:\Users\zhaden\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music\Final Fantasy 7 Piano Collection\Final Fantasy VII Piano Collection\05 Fighting.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> <br>
             Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>

    </body>
</html> 


html, body {
        overflow-x: hidden;     /* This is to ensure we don't allow horizontal scroll */
    }

    body {
        margin: 0px;            /* This is to delete the default margin */
    }

    #audioBar {
        width: 100%;            /* This is to set the audio bar to the full width of the page */
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code to point you in the right direction:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Wimpy Player - Fullscreen</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">


<!-- The following META tags are used to inform mobile-device browsers to present this page in full-screen mode.-->
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Wimpy Player" />


<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    /* Make page fill device window */
    html, body {
        width : 100%;
        height : 100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color:#484848;
    }
    /* For the Player Instance DIV */
    .full {
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        width : 100%;
        height : 100%;
    }
</style>


<!-- Prevent entire page from "bouncing" -->
<script>document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){event.preventDefault();},false);</script>


</head>
<body>


<!-- NOTE: Change data-media to target media files or a playlist. -->
<video class="full" src="video.webm" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>


</body>
</html>
```

BTW: I recommend checking into www.wimpyplayer.com, they've got a nice new HTML-5 player.

Answer (score 0):

The audio tag with the "controls" attribute uses the browser's default player, which you cannot style. The workaround is to not use the browser controls and use some of your own, you can do this with javascript.

You can write something yourself, or use something like this: [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum width for the player is 800px wide.  I would set this player to hidden and follow ShemSeger's answer on using another library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the audio webkit element:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure, video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```